# increase performance of a linq query using contains

Tags: winforms, linq

I have a winforms app where I have a Telerik dropdownchecklist that lets the user select a group of state names.
Using EF and the database is stored in Azure SQL.
The code then hits a database of about 17,000 records and filters the results to only include states that are checked.

Works fine.  I am wanting to update a count on the screen whenever they change the list box.

This is the code, in the itemCheckChanged event:

```
var states = stateDropDownList.CheckedItems.Select(i => i.Value.ToString()).ToList();
var filteredStops = (from stop in aDb.Stop_address_details where states.Contains(stop.Stop_state) select stop).ToArray();

ExportInfo_tb.Text = "Current Stop Count: " + filteredStops.Count();
```

It works, but it is slow.
I tried to load everything into a memory variable then querying that vs the database but can't seem to figure out how to do that.

Any suggestions?

Improvement:
I picked up a noticeable improvement by limiting the amount of data coming down by:

```
 var filteredStops = (from stop in aDb.Stop_address_details where states.Contains(stop.Stop_state) select stop.Stop_state).ToList();
```

And better yet --

```
   int count = (from stop in aDb.Stop_address_details where 
                         states.Contains(stop.Stop_state) 
                     select stop).Count();

        ExportInfo_tb.Text = "Current Stop Count: " + count.ToString();
```

Comment: What kind of LINQ? And do you really think the performance of the query is affected by the fact you're using Winforms? Because that was in your title.

Comment: You expect in-memory query to be faster than DB lookup? That's most likely not going to happen. Also, did you look into the SQL that's being generated? That's what you should start with.

Comment: Yes..I would expect in memory to be faster than over the internet then doing a SQL lookup.  Wrong?

Comment: Add `AsEnumerable` call after `aDv.Stop_address_details` and you'll see.

Comment: Wrong @MostlyLucid - your first two queries materialize a lot of data from the DB to your program - the last one only selects the count, hence it's much faster

Comment: Are we not talking apples and oranges here?  Obviously pulling less data is going to be faster, so that is the apple part and that part of the solution needs to happen regardless.  But if I need to go back to the database over and over, pulling the data down once into memory, then searching it locally in ram would have to be faster would it not?  It was also counting everytime the listbox was updated, on the screen this was happening 27 times in a row as the listbox was being populated.  That was a third area.  In the end multiple refactorings made this solution run much, much faster.

Comment: @ moderators, I will clean this question and comments up in a couple days after the dust settles a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance of you query, actually, has nothing to do with `Contiains`, in this case.  Contains is pretty performant.  The problem, as you picked up on in your third solution, is that you are pulling far more data over the network than required.

In your first solution you are pulling back all of the rows from the server with the matching stop state and performing the count locally.  This is the worst possible approach.  You are pulling back data just to count it and you are pulling back far more data than you need.

In your second solution you limited the data coming back to a single field which is why the performance improved.  This could have resulted in a significant improvement if your table is really wide.  The problem with this is that you are still pulling back all the data just to count it locally.

In your third solution EF will translate the `.Count()` method into a query that performs the count for you.  So the count will happen on the server and the only data returned is a single value; the result of count.  Since network latency CAN often be (but is not always) the longest step when performing a query, returning less data can often result in significant gains in query speed.

The query translation of your final solution should look something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value]
FROM [Stop_address_details] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[Stop_state] IN (@p0)
```